# jQuery keypress enter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, keypress

I tried to use keypress to get an text from  to update a text in . My html looks like this:

```
<p>words words words <i>test</i> more words</p>
<div id="newWord">
   <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="New Hashtag"></input>
   </form>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keypress(
        function (e) {
            var currentInput = $("input").val();
            console.log(currentInput);
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                console.log('hello');
            }
        }
    );
})
```

My console log doesn't log on first keypress, how can I help it? Also my "hello" never log. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Though I am not sure if this is the reason or not, this might be a good idea to try `.on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/. Also you can get the current object firing the event using `$(this)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `keyup` event to capture first keyboard char.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(
        function (e) {
            var currentInput = $("input").val();
            console.log(currentInput);
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                console.log('hello');
                alert('hello');
            }
        }
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>words words words <i>test</i> more words</p>
<div id="newWord">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="New Hashtag">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Note:** Hitting `Enter` key will submit the form and it will redirect the page. You might not see the console message for "hello"

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Any ideas why on my enter doesn't log (the "hello")?

Comment: enter key is working but it's submitting the form... that's why you are not seeing it. Updated my code above, I've put `alert` which you can see `enter` is working fine.

Comment: yes keyup works, keypress not

Answer (score 0):

The `keypress` function fires right as a key is pressed. You want to use `keyup` as that will fire when the key is released.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that when Muthu below suggested. Any ideas why on my enter doesn't log (the "hello")?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keyup` as keypress will trigger value as soon as a key is pressed which is separate from releasing a key.

There are few changes that can be done. `input` is a self closing tag. Also it is better to use `$(this)` inside the function as it will get the value only from the input from where the event is triggered.

There may be a catch here. On pressing `enter/return` key you may see the form is getting submitted

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function(e) {
    var currentInput = $(this).val();
    console.log(currentInput);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('hello');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>words words words <i>test</i> more words</p>
<div id="newWord">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="New Hashtag">
  </form>
</div>
```